# For in loop over dict gives TypeError: string indices must be integers

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop

I have a dict with 11 items in it, here's a scree shot from Spyder variable explorer:

[image]

```
def buildDF(result_set):
    master_dm = []
    for p in result_set:
        rows = p['reports']
        master_dm.append(rows)
    return(master_dm)

sessions1DF = buildDF(sessions1)
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

When I view sessions1 I can see that it's a dict with the 11 items per the screen above. Double clicking on one of the items shows the reports inside each item:

[image]

Why am I getting this error and how can I build a new list with the 11 reports lists which are nested under each item in result_set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A similar question can be found here: [Iterating over dictionaries using 'for' loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294889/iterating-over-dictionaries-using-for-loops)

From what I can gather you sessions1 is a dictionary containing other dictionaries, so to iterate over the items as it would appear you would like to, you would need to use `.items()` method on the dictionary i.e:

```
def buildDF(result_set):
    master_dm = []
    for key, p in result_set.items():
        rows = p['reports']
        master_dm.append(rows)
    return(master_dm)
```

What you are doing at the moment is just iterating over the list of keys which are strings. This means the line `p['reports']` in your original code is trying to access the `'reports'` element of whatever key it is looking at at the time. This cannot be done as strings can be only indexed with integers - hence the error.

Answer (score 1):

When iterating over the dictionary try calling the `dict.items()` method:

```
sessions1 = {10000:'val1',100000:'val2',2000:'val3',3000:'val4',4000:'val5',5000:'val6',6000:'val7',7000:'val8',8000:'val9',9000:'val10',10000:'val11'}
def buildDF(result_set):
    master_dm = []
    for k,v in result_set.items():
        master_dm.append(v)
    return(master_dm)

sessions1DF = buildDF(sessions1)

print(sessions1DF)
# ['val11', 'val2', 'val6', 'val5', 'val3', 'val8', 'val4', 'val9', 'val7', 'val10']
```