# In Django why the error "TypeError at / string indices must be integers"?

Tags: python, django, api

I am trying to learn how to save in Django part of a json content coming from a kraken api. Going through several examples here on stackoverflow i came up with this code:

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from meal_app.models import Kraken
import requests

def get_krakens(request):
    all_krakens = {}
    url ='https://api.kraken.com/0/public/Assets' 
    response = requests.get(url)
    data = response.json()

    
    for i in data:
        kraken_data = Kraken(
            name = i['altname']
            )
        kraken_data.save()
        all_krakens = Kraken.objects.all().order_by('-id')

    return render (request, 'krakens/kraken.html', { "all_krakens": 
    all_krakens} )
```

When i try to run it appears:
[image]

How can i solve this error? My json is visible in my console but i cannot access the value 'altname'.
Your help would be really appreciated.

```
/Users/davidmoreira/Documents/crypto/djangokrakenapi/meal_project/meal_app/views.py, line 14, in get_krakens
            name = i['altname']
```

Comment: what is your data `data = response.json()` can you print this out ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [For in loop over dict gives TypeError: string indices must be integers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51344283/for-in-loop-over-dict-gives-typeerror-string-indices-must-be-integers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looping over a dictionary loops over its keys, not its values. And you're looping over `data`, while you want to loop over `data['results']`. You want:

```
for i in data['result'].values():
```

Comment: This solution worked perfectly Jasmijn, excellent help.

Answer (score 1):

Your "i" is in the form of a string. You need to convert it to an object first.
Using `i = json.loads(i)`

Answer (score 1):

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from meal_app.models import Kraken
import requests

def get_krakens(request):
    all_krakens = {}
    url ='https://api.kraken.com/0/public/Assets' 
    response = requests.get(url)
    data = response.json()

    
    for i in data:
        kraken_data = Kraken(
            name = data['result'][i]['altname']
            )
        kraken_data.save()
        all_krakens = Kraken.objects.all().order_by('-id')

    return render (request, 'krakens/kraken.html', { "all_krakens": 
    all_krakens} )
```